# How to correctly set PATH in gvim?

Tags: linux, bash, vim

When I run vim from terminal PATH is the same as my terminal. But when I run gvim PATH is not reading properly.

Currently I'm using this fix to launch gvim, but it feel dirty:

```
bash -lc gvim
```

I tried adding the path to vimrc with:

> let
>   PATH='/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/opt/project-neon/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/.cabal/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin'

But it didn't work like I expected.

This doesn't work either:

```
set shell=bash\ --login
```

How can I make this work nicely in my vimrc?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: You should avoid having such a long `PATH`. I would suggest adding `$HOME/bin/` to your `PATH` and putting symlinks there. And you should set your `PATH` in your `.bashrc` ...

Comment: I set the PATH in bashrc aldready but it doesn't work. Only the command `bash -lc gvim` works for some reason...

Comment: You might need to logout and login again after changing `$HOME/.bashrc` and you should check, e.g. with `echo $PATH` in a terminal, that your `PATH` is what you want. I guess your question is unrelated to `vim` actually!

Comment: I mean that PATH and bashrc work on terminal fine, but not on vim unless I use that command. My PATH works fine everywhere else. It is vim related, I saw question with similar problem, but on OSX, but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: A well configured `vim` don't change the `PATH` it has inherited at startup time.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: There are other similar questions on StackOverflow, so it is not uncommon, but all of them apply to Mac not Ubuntu.

Comment: @lokhura, the underlying problem is the same on Mac OS X and Ubuntu: GUI programs don't have the same environment variables but the solutions are slightly different. While the solution seemingly changes every couple of big cats on Mac OS X, it's always the same on Ubuntu. It's difficult to automate in both cases and forces us to go through hoops and loops to get a unified environment, though.

Comment: From your comment on @romainl's answer, it looks as though you already have an answer:  add `let $PATH = '...'` to your vimrc or gvimrc file.  You could add a test:  only set the path if it is the unhelpful default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't change your `PATH` from Vim. It is inherited from the process that launches Vim and that's there, outside of Vim that you must fix your issue.

You didn't tell us how and where you set your `PATH`, what desktop environment (if any) or even what value you get in GVim, by the way.

-- edit --

When you lauch GVim from the command-line, it inherits your shell's environment variables and you should get the same `$PATH` with `$ gvim` as you do with `$ vim`.

When you start GVim from a menu or an icon, it inherits the desktop environment's `PATH` which is defined regardless of your shell's `PATH` so the output of `:echo $PATH` is different from what you should get in my shell.

In my opinion, the most effective way to get GVim to honor your custom `PATH` is simply to change the `Exec` line in its `gvim.desktop` file from:

```
Exec=gvim -f %F
```

to:

```
Exec=env PATH=/your/complete/path gvim -f %F
```

Comment: Apparently you can with `let $PATH`, I missed the `$`. I get my regular environment but not my user's. I'm on Ubuntu. Found someone with same problem that posted the solution I'm currently using, but I'd like to know if it's possible to fix in vimrc, without modifying my launcher. http://notgeeklycorrect.com/2011/02/08/launch-gvim-macvim-with-the-correct-path-variable.

Comment: Even if you *could* change your `PATH` inside or from `vim` you should never do that.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is already answered, but the following may help someone else :

If you set your PATH in your `~/.profile` then gvim will pick it up in from the logged in session - without having to modify the gvim.desktop file with an explicit path. (But you do need to re-login for it to take effect).

See [Ubuntu Session-wide environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4ALw.profile) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
let $PATH .=':/path/to/bin:/path/to/another/bin'
```

Then it started working fine. I was trying to setup vim-go (golang support) for vim. I had been having issues with it since vim-go was complaining that go executable isn't in path. This has been the issue with vim-gtk. After I set the above configuration in .vimrc file issues got resolved.